# Smallest number divisible by 10^n with digits totaling n -- Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I need to do this program:

```
minor :: Integer -> Integer
```

such that (minor n) is the smallest number divisible by 10^n whose digits add up to n. For example,

```
minor 5   ==  500000
minor 20  ==  29900000000000000000000
length (show (minor 67^35+3)) == a
```

I have tried this

```
minor :: Integer -> Integer
minor n = minimum [x | x <- [n*10^n..], rem x 10^n == 0, sum (digits x) == n]

digits :: Integer -> [Integer]
digits n = [read[d] | d <- show n]
```

But it's very inefficient, because the computer gets stuck. How would they do that? Thanks.

Comment: First, come up with a good algorithm.  A brute-force search isn't going to work, but a simple greedy algorithm will be very fast.  The two examples from your homework should make it pretty clear what that algorithm is.

Comment: I have tried find a relation between the numbers, but I don't find anything

Comment: Hint: when is a number divisable by 10^n?

Comment: When it's divisible by 10

Comment: ("When it's divisible by 10" -- No, the implication would go other way round: if a number is divisible by 10^n, then it is divisible by 10.)

Comment: @mathandtic: yes, but that will not give you much speedup, it means the last *n* digits are zeros.

Comment: As a side note, your `minor` calls `minimum` on an infinite list, so it can't possibly terminate.

Comment: Indeed, `minimum` should be `head`, since it is guaranteed that `x` increases.

Comment: First, make a function that produces the smallest number whose digits add up to `n`, then multiply the result by `10^n`.

Comment: Hint: ``n `div` 9`` tells you the number of nines that will be in the output.

Comment: @4castle I don't understand your hiny

Comment: ``5 `div` 9`` is `0`, so there are zero nines in the output `500000`. ``20 `div` 9`` is `2`, so there are two nines in `29900000000000000000000`.

Comment: Ahh, but can I put that in the code? I get stuck on that @4castle

Comment: @mathandtic: not directly, Haskell is not a *constraint programming* language (and even if it was, it would still require some tricks).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What would you do?

Comment: I get stuck, I've been dealing with the problem for three hours.

Comment: @mathandtic: perhaps a first way to speed up this algorithm enourmously (at least compared with the current appoach), is taking hops of 10^n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 key observations which can be made for this problem:

1. The number always ends with `n` zeros.
2. The rest of the digits are all `9` (except maybe the first digit).

This means you can find the number of nines by dividing by `9`, and you can find the left-most digit by using the remainder from that division.

```
 20 = 2 + (2 * 9) = 2 + 9 + 9      ⇒ 299
 35 = 8 + (3 * 9) = 8 + 9 + 9 + 9  ⇒ 8999
```

In Haskell, you can use `quotRem` to divide by `9` and get both the quotient and remainder at the same time. You can then use these numbers to construct the output number.

```
minor :: Integer -> Integer
minor n = ((r + 1) * (10 ^ q) - 1) * (10 ^ n)
    where (q, r) = n `quotRem` 9
```

---

If you're only interested in calculating the number of digits in the output, you can find that out by observing the parts of `minor` that serve as exponents to `10`, namely `q` and `n`. If `r` isn't `0`, you can add `1` more digit.

```
minorLength :: Integer -> Integer
minorLength n = signum r + q + n
   where (q, r) = n `quotRem` 9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the number of digits in the minor of a number without ever computing the number's minor directly, and this is important if you want to know the number of digits in the minors of large inputs.

Willem describes the main first trick: the minor of a number is a single digit, followed by a bunch of 9s, followed by a bunch of 0s. Since we only care *how many* there are, we can compute those things directly.

```
numLeadingDigits n = signum (n `mod` 9)
num9s n = n `div` 9
num0s n = n
```

Now the complete length is just the sum of these.

```
numDigitsInMinor n = numLeadingDigits n + num9s n + num0s n
```

This can indeed be run on enormous inputs:

```
> numDigitsInMinor (67^35 + 3)
9086059680492581695084814449385436459012675694436486492711692052
```

Computing this minor explicitly would have required 10^63 bytes of memory, many orders of magnitude over the total amount of storage ever produced by the human race in all of history.

Comment: The question doesn't just ask about finding the number of digits, it asks about calculating the number's minor directly.

Comment: @4castle `length (show (minor 67^35+3)) == a` is a direct quote from the question. I took it to be the main computation of interest; this required some human judgment rather than a direct, literal reading of the question, but that is common in SO questions.

Answer (score 1):

## Calculating the smallest number

Instead of using a brute force algorithm, we first better think how we can find such number.

A number that is dividably by *10<sup>n</sup>* has *n* tailing zeros. For example for *n=3*, then the numbers are 1000, 2000, 3000, etc.

Next we want to find the *smallest* this means that the digits we have control over (the ones before the last *n* should be as large as possible at the tail, in order to be small at the lead). The digits are limited between zero and nine.

So we can look for the smallest number where the sum of the digits is *n* with:

```
smallest_sum :: (Num n, Ord n) => n -> n
smallest_sum 0 = 0
smallest_sum x = d + 10 * smallest_sum (x - d)
    where d = min 9 x
```

So here `d = min 9 x` is the digit we calculate, and the digits before are calculated with recursion.

So now the smallest number that satisfies these constraints is:

```
minor :: Integral i => i -> i
minor n = smallest_sum n * 10 ^ n
```

So this works in *linear* time with the *value* of `n`.

Examples:

```
Prelude> minor 5
500000
Prelude> minor 20
29900000000000000000000
Prelude> minor 0
0
Prelude> minor 1
10
Prelude> minor 2
200
Prelude> minor 3
3000
Prelude> minor 4
40000
Prelude> minor 5
500000
Prelude> minor 6
6000000
Prelude> minor 7
70000000
Prelude> minor 8
800000000
Prelude> minor 9
9000000000
Prelude> minor 10
190000000000
```

## The length of that number

But this will, like @DanielWagner says, not suffice to calculate the length, since that number will be gigantic: for `67^35+3` it will contain approximately 10^64 digits, this can not be stored in memory. The point is that we do *not* have to calculate the number itself in order to calculate the length, we can derive the length with:

```
length_minor :: Integral i => i -> i
length_minor n = length_smallest_sum n + n
    where length_smallest_sum n = div (n+8) 9
```

So a very compact function that calculates it is:

```
length_minor :: Integral i => i -> i
length_minor n = div (n+8) 9 + n
```

or even more compact (but if we use a small integer representation, a bit dangerous for overflow):

```
length_minor :: Integral i => i -> i
length_minor n = div (10*n+8) 9
```

Comment: `smallest_sum` calcules the minimum number that his digits sum `n`, isn't it?

Comment: @mathandtic: yes.

Comment: ...but this trick will still be insufficient for computing `length . show . minor $ 67^53 + 3`. For that you need one more tweak to compute `length . show . minor` directly instead of computing the intermediate value produced by `minor`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Can you think of anything?

Comment: @DanielWagner: well I did not notice that we had to calculate the length :)

Comment: Okay, don't worry :)

Comment: The last thing I don't really understand this `d + 10 * smallest_sum (x - d)`

Comment: @mathandtic: well `d` is the last digit, but it is possible that there are more digits to the left, so we subtract `d` from `x`, and perform a recursive call to calculate the remaining digits, to get these before the current digit, we multiply with 10.